# How to send push notification to all my registered devices on Azure

Tags: android, azure, xamarin.forms

i want to send Notifications to all my devices not just 10 random devices using azure [image]

how to do that ?

thx in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we leave `Send to Tag Expression` field empty it will only send to 10 random devices .

[image]

#### The steps to send all registered devices

1. Register templates with tag `default` ,check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-services/azure-notification-hub#register-templates-and-tags-with-the-azure-notification-hub%20.).
2. Set the `Send to Tag expression` to default , it will send messages to applications that have registered a template for the default tag, check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/azure-services/azure-notification-hub#test-notifications-in-the-azure-portal) .